# BlackBerry - bbwp.exe returns file not found error

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

I have created my first hello-world application on BlackBerry and I am using Eclipse to write the code.  Unfortunately I get java.io.filenotfound when I create the .cod file from the command prompt with bbwp.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Use `jde` tool, build your application, if you are not using any third party library your code file will be generated properly and you will be able to test it on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running the JDE in Administrator mode?

Some OS restricts write access to directories in the "Program Files" structure, for security.

I got similar issue in Vista OS.. I changed permission in JDE installed directory and it worked perfectly..

Comment: If vista or win 7 is concerned i installed my JDE in a folder other than program files in my case (D:/BBDev) and i can run it as if the os is xp.